# Difference of Upper Bounded Type and normal class behavior

Tags: scala, generics

I am studying Generics in Scala and I can't understand the difference between a "normal" class hierarchy and the Upper Bound type.

Looking at the example below: Cage can receive the class Animal, which means that I can pass either the class Animal or the class Dog. The same is valid for the upper bound parameter. What is the practical difference between them? When should I use one or the other?

```
class Animal
class Dog extends Animal

class Cage(animal: Animal)
val cage = new Cage(new Dog)

class AnotherCage[A <: Animal](animal: A)
val anotherCage = new AnotherCage(new Dog)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One difference is in the *static* type of `animal` parameter where in the former case it is typed as `Animal` whilst in latter case it is typed as `Dog` because the type parameter `A` is substituted with concrete type `Dog` . To see the difference try adding a `sound` method to `Dog` like so

```
class Animal
class Dog extends Animal {
  def sound = "woof"
}

class Cage(val animal: Animal)
val cage = new Cage(new Dog)

class AnotherCage[A <: Animal](val animal: A)
val anotherCage = new AnotherCage(new Dog)

cage.animal.sound         // error
anotherCage.animal.sound  // ok
```

Note how compiler is not aware of `sound` method in the first case despite the fact that the runtime class referenced by `animal` argument is `Dog`.

Parameterized types can provide stronger type-safety and help avoid the need for type casting with `asInstanceOf`. For example, let's say we have a `Dog` and a `Cat`

```
class Animal
class Dog extends Animal
class Cat extends Animal
```

and we define a method that opens only cages containing `Dog`s

```
def openDogCage(cage: Cage): Dog =
  if (cage.animal.isInstanceOf[Dog]) cage.animal.asInstanceOf[Dog]
  else throw new IllegalArgumentException

def openAnotherDogCage(cage: AnotherCage[Dog]): Dog = cage.animal
```

but erroneously provide a cage with a `Cat`

```
val dog: Dog = openDogCage(new Cage(new Cat))               // runtime error
val dog: Dog = openAnotherDogCage(new AnotherCage(new Cat)) // compile-time error
```

then notice how parameterzied types caught the error at compile-time before the program even ran. Also notice how in definition of `openDogCage` when using just subtyping we had to manually perform a type cast with `asInstanceOf` to convince the compiler that method returns a `Dog`.

Comment: Owwww that answered all my questions <3 thank you so much

Comment: @leportella if this answers your question, please consider up voting it and accepting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I don't think I have enough karma to upvote it. I tried on the first time I saw the message :(  Sorry